# How to get all work items in an iteration?

Tags: c#, tfs

I am using TFS client side libraries, e.g Microsoft.TeamFoundation.* assemblies... Given that I have an Iteration name, how do I retrieve all the work items that belong to it?

I've tried the following using the Query object:

```
var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TfsUri"]);
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(uri);
var wiStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

var queryText = "select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = 'VieroSAT'  and [System.State] = 'Dev'  order by [System.Id]";
var query = new Query(wiStore, queryText);
```

but I can't figure out how to limit results by Iteration Name.  And I'd much rather return these values using the TFS assemblies, but I can't find the appropriate method.

So my questions...

1. How to return a list of all work items in an iteration, using the TFS Assemblies only (e.g. no queries).
2. If #1 is not possible, how do I do the above but using a Query object.

Comment: You can build a query VS / Web Access and save it to a file, and examine the WIQL that is uses, then use that in your app.

Comment: @DaveShaw Can you expand?  How exactly do I save the query to file?

Comment: File, Save as.... In visual studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a quick way of testing this, but according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx), you can use the `Under` comparison operator in your query. However, I'm not sure what field you would use in that where clause to compare against the iteration name. Perhaps something like this:

```
select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]
from WorkItems
where
  [System.TeamProject] = 'VieroSAT'
  and [System.State] = 'Dev'
  and [System.IterationPath] Under 'Iteration1'
order by [System.Id]
```

Comment: This query returns an error, stating that error is caused by [Work Item]

Comment: That's what I'm not sure of, what the field should be. I can't seem to find anything on the list of fields available for querying.

Comment: @AngryHacker based on DaveShaw's comment, try the following: [System.AreaId] = 15  or  [System.NodeName] = 'Iteration1'

Comment: I have updated the query above with [System.IterationPath]. The easy way to make working queried is to create then in Visual Studio and the save them to the desktop and open in Notepad....